# Graph of ordinary differential equation different under wolfram alpha and octave

Tags: graph, octave

I am using this octave code for solving differential equation.

```
 # Define the right-hand side of the equation:
xvall= -11 ;#xvall
xvalu= 10 ;#xvalu
range=5000;
function ret=f(x,t);ret= t ;end;

# ywill be the values of the function at these moments of time.
t=linspace(xvall,xvalu,range);
y=lsode ('f', 2, linspace(xvall,xvalu,range));
y
plot(t,y);
```

i got the graph like this .

[image]

But when the same conditions are passed to wolfram alpha 
I am getting the graph from 60 to 0 for y value

graph is [image]
why is the graph behaving differently in two situations.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Runge-Kutta+method%2C+dy%2Fdx+%3D+x%2C+y%280%29+%3D+2%2C+from+-11+to+10%2C+h+%3D+0.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify an initial value problem for an ordinary differential equation you need to define the initial condition. Here for Octave you have specified `x(-11) = 2` since `xvall = -11` and for Wolfram Alpha you have specified `y(0) = 2`. That is why you have two different solutions.

**Octave**

Octave's `lsode (f,x_0,ts)` solves the following initial value problem

```
 dx/dt = t
 x(t_0) = x_0
 t in ts
```

Here `ts` is specified as a set of points in the interval `[t_0,t_1]`. You have specified `t_0 = -11`, `t_1 = 10`.

In closed form the solution to this problem is `x = (t^2 - 117) / 2`

**Wolfram**

For Wolfram you have used the semi-formal syntax:

```
Runge-Kutta method, dy/dx = x, y(0) = 2, from -11 to 10, h = 0.25
```

In closed form the solution to this problem would be `y = (x^2 + 4) /2`

The corresponding initial value problem is clearly different. Hence different results.